# should i use firestore database to store a boolean value for my button state (pressed/unpressed)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a food delivery app using Firestore to populate a RecyclerView, I have a button in every view in RecyclerView. I just want to know if I use Firestore boolean to save my buttons state in view, and give permission to the user to change the boolean value when the button is pressed. it will be a good idea to save the state of RecyclerView's view.
The problem is if a user changes the boolean value in Firestore,  all the users will get the same value and all the users will get some state of the button.
is there any way to overcome this problem, please help?

Comment: What exactly are you displaying in the Recycler View? User objects?

Comment: In Recycler view i m displaying Product (name, price, add to cart button)

Comment: So the boolean value is related to each product then?

Comment: All the products have their seprate boolean in firestore, this is my Product model class (String name, String price, boolean for button)

Comment: I just want to save state of button in recyclerview so if user browse throgh many category and comes back to selected product, product remain selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment:

> All the products have their separate boolean in Firestore, this is my Product model class (String name, String price, boolean for button)

It's not a solution since that boolean value is the same for all users. What you have to do is to add an array type field inside each product document. When a user clicks the button add his UID inside the array. In this way, you'll always know which user clicked the button.

After doing this change, when displaying products, simply check if the UID exists in the array. If it exists enable the button otherwise disable it.

Comment: You're very welcome, Gurdeep.

Comment: Done. One more thing to ask brother, Can u suggest which way is better (save a state for each row of RecyclerView by using method onSaveInstanceState ) or (save user UID in Firestore to save button as pressed).

Comment: Save in Firestore, as it will always be present there.